# Navigate to child router from named outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to open the expanded item on some grid of components that are rendered inside the named outlet. For that purpose I've created a children to my named outlet path.

I'm using the Angular 7 and already tried some guides from other posts. Also it seems possible to make by just specify another outlet.

**Routing**:

```
{
  path: 'my-path',
  outlet: 'view',
  component: MyComponent,
  data: {
    animation: 'bottom-left-scale'
  },
  children: [
  {
    path: 'project',
    component: ExpandedProjectComponent
  }]
}
```

**in html**:

```
<app-project [id]="project.id" [thumbnail]="project.thumbnail" [name]="project.name" [routerLink]="[{outlets: { view: 'my-path/project' }}]">
</app-project>
```

But when trying to navigate to it get the error that

> *ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'my-path'.*

Using tracing shows it like this - `url: "/(view:my-path/(view:my-path/project))"` where project should be expanded item. How can i navigate to smth like `/(view:my-path/project)` or `/(view:my-path)/project`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, trying it from routerLink directive fails. But using the `router.navigate` works.

---

**app.routing.ts** stays the same.

---

**ExpandedProjectComponent**

```
openProject(id) {
    this.router.navigate('project', {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```